# How to encapsulate mastic adhesive and seal concrete garage floor

Tags: concrete, garage, epoxy, mastic

Part of my garage floor has what I believe to be asbestos vinyl tiles. My plan is to take appropriate precautions and get the tiles up. Then leave the mastic adhesive underneath, since it also probably has asbestos, and encapsulate the adhesive with something like Mapei Ecoprim Grip primer. I was thinking of covering the whole garage floor with that and then doing an epoxy coating over.

Is there a better way to do this? Or other ideas? Will my idea even work?

Comment: Why not have the tile and mastic tested prior to doing all the work.  You may be encapsulating for nothing.

Comment: That's risky. If it tests positive, then I'd have to disclose there is asbestos if I sell and buyers want full remediation from an asbestos abatement company, which is expensive. I'd prefer to encapsulate and forget about it. The vinyl tiles are not a huge risk because they are non-friable

Comment: So you prefer to take the , "what I don't know, won't hurt me " route.   Your call.

Comment: Well, not exactly. I'm gonna assume there is asbestos and take precautions. Plastic off the doorway, wear P100 mask, have fans pushing air out, etc. I think I can pull up the tiles easily but I don't want to start scrapping/grinding adhesive. So I thought maybe there was a better way to encapsulate it and also prep it for an epoxy coating or good wear surface

Comment: Have you considered leaving the tiles and covering them with some sort of flooring epoxy? Completely eliminates the necessity of all the PPE and the "scary" asbestos remediation look to the whole house that might terrify the neighborhood and make you the pariah.

Comment: I like that idea. Do you have a product you would recommend for that?